# Problems using Indy10 to access a Mashape API Service

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, mashape

I am trying to write a client application which consumes a Mashape API service using Delphi XE3 and Indy10, but I have run into a bit of a snag.

Here is what I have tried:

I placed `TIdHTTP` and`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` components on my form and linked them together using the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property. I then placed a button and memo on my form and placed the following bit of code on the buttons `OnClick` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
 IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Mashape-Key: ','<my_api_key>');
 Memo1.Lines.Text := IdHTTP1.Get('https://hbrd-v1.p.mashape.com/anime/log-horizon');
end;
```

I then start up my app and when I press the button the app will wait for a moment and then spit out a `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` error message.  Pressing the button a 2nd time will cause a `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error` message.

I already checked to see if I had the needed SSL Library files on my system and I do, and I have tested my credentials time and time again and they appear to be correct, and I know the url is correct, so I must be missing something in my code to cause these errors to display.  I was hoping someone with more experience in this area might be able to offer some advice.

**Update:** here is `TRESTClient` code that works:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IPPeerClient, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  REST.Response.Adapter, REST.Client, Data.Bind.Components,
  Data.Bind.ObjectScope;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://hbrd-v1.p.mashape.com/anime/log-horizon';
 RESTRequest1.Execute;
 Memo1.Lines.Text := RESTResponse1.Content;

// The only thing not shown here is the RESTRequest1.Params which are
// Name: 'X-Mashape-Key'
// Value: 'my-api-key'
// Kind: pkHTTPHEADER
// Everything else is included here which isn't much.
end;

end.
```

I want to do the same thing with `TIdHTTP`.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to know what is actually happening without seeing the actual HTTP messages going back and forth.  When an HTTP response indicates an error, an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception is raised, and its `ErrorMessage` property contains the body of the server's response.  Does it give you any indication about why the error occurred?

However, you do need to change this:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Mashape-Key: ','<my_api_key>');
```

To this:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Mashape-Key'] := '<my_api_key>';
```

And get rid of the programmic `IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;` assignment, since you already handled that in the form designer.

Aside from that, a `403` error means your credentials are NOT accepted by the server.  I don't see you assigning any credentials to the `TIdHTTP.Request.Username` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties in your code, are you doing that in the form designer?

`TIdHTTP` uses a plugin system for handling HTTP authentication schemes. If the server allows `BASIC` authentication, you can set the `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` property to true so `BASIC` is used as a default when no other authentication scheme is available.  You can use the `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event to see which authentications the server actually supports.

If the server wants a non-`BASIC` authentication, you will need to add the relevant `IdAuthentication...` to your `uses` clause to enable that plugin.  For example, `IdAuthenticationDigest` for `DIGEST` authentication, `IdAuthenticationNTLM` for `NTLM` authentication, etc.  Or, add the `IdAllAuthentications` unit instead to enable all of the plugins.

If you need to use an HTTP authentication that Indy does not support (`OATH`, for instance), you can either:

1. use `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']` to provide the relevant credential data manually.
2. implement a custom `TIdAuthentication`-derived class, and assign an instance of it to the `TIdHTTP.Request.Authorization` property, or its class type to the `VAuthenticationClass` parameter of the `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event.

Comment: I made the changes per your instructions and even after adding my username and password to the request (they are not required btw) and checking Basic Authentication being TRUE or FALSE. The errors still occur. What is strange to me is that I used the exact same values in the TRestClient contols and they work just fine, but they are too slow for my needs which is why I wanted to use INDY instead in the hope that it would be faster. I am unsure how to proceed now.

Comment: `TRESTClient` uses `TIdHTTP` internally. If you capture the raw HTTPS request being sent by `TRESTClient` ([Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) supports HTTPS, and `TRESTClient` has `ProxyServer/ProxyPort` properties), you can configure `TIdHTTP` to replicate the request values as needed.  Or, show your `TRESTClient` code, and I will translate it to `TIdHTTP` for you.

Comment: Here is a Pastebin of the Unit from the TRESTClient version: http://pastebin.com/7HitQDCX I hope this is what you were looking for anyway, it's extremely simple, but it works, it's just abit slow when fetching results.

Comment: For future reference, don't post your code to pastebin or any other external site.  Embed the code directly in your question.  I have updated your question for you, and will get you a `TIdHTTP` translation soon.

Comment: just checking in to see if you managed to get this working with INDY like it does with the Rest client?  If you need my api key to test with I can share it with you.

Comment: Sorry, I have not had time to look at it yet.  But I have not forgotten about it.

Comment: No problem, you are doing me a favor so no rush and thanks once again for your assistance